# Preencher Modal com dados do Banco

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uma Grid em que eu clico no botão editar e ela deveria trazer dados do BD em um Modal mas não está funcionando.

**Segue o codigo.**

### Botão

***Obs.(O Botão está trazendo o id)***

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-fornecedor-id="<?php echo $rowPedido->id; ?>" >
```

### Div para Retorno dos Dados

```
<div class="fetched-data"></div>
```

### Jquery

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('fornecedor-id');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'readDetails.php', //Here you will fetch records 
            data :  'rowid='+ rowid, //Pass $id
            success : function(data){
            $('.fetched-data').html(data);//Show fetched data from database
            }
        });
     });
});
```

### Php (readDetails.php)

```
 $conn = new PDO('**dados da conexão**'); 


//Include database connection
if($_POST['rowid']) {
   $id = $_POST['rowid']; //escape string
    // Run the Query
    // Fetch Records
    // Echo the data you want to show in modal


             $sql = $conn->prepare( "SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE id = $id");
             $sql->execute();
            $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


 }
```

Comment: Um erro já está na linha  `var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('fornecedor-id');` onde o atributo `fornecedor-id` não existe, portanto troque `fornecedor-id` para `id` apenas. Esse é um indicio, os demais dependem do resto do seu código que não está disponivel para analisar melhor.

Comment: Opa obrigado pelo toque na verdade o fornecedor-id era um teste que eu estava fazendo e esqueci de tirar acredito que o problema está no **readDetails.php** não retorna nada

Comment: Ponha um `print_r($result)` no **readDetails.php** para ver o que retorna.

Comment: Não retorna Nada uma tela em branco

Comment: Quando você diz que o botão está trazendo o id é porque o atributo está sendo preenchido corretamente no HTML ou porque no JavaScript ele está sendo corretamente lido? Minha dúvida é se após a linha `var rowid = ....` o valor está na variável `rowid`.

Comment: É porque está sendo preenchido corretamente no HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Altera o ajax para:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data : { rowid : rowid },
    ...
})
```

Comment: Acabei de alterar mas não deu certo

Comment: Depois do if que tem no readDetails.php, coloca echo "SELECT * FROM Pedidos WHERE id = $id", e veja se o $id está sendo informado. Se não aparecer um id é porque ele nem tá sendo enviado via ajax.

Comment: Você pode colocar também um print_r($_POST), pra ver o que está sendo enviado pelo ajax.